# How to Add Facebook Messanger Checkbox plugin on My Facebook Game Page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I have Created Facebook App From [FB Developer Page](http://developers.facebook.com) and I want to render FB chatbot Plugin in that app but currently it gives me an error as below

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/plugins/customerchat.php?app_id=142034109YYYYYY&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FlY4eZXm_YWu.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df287424cc4efd58%26domain%3Dgame.XXXXXX.in%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgame.XXXXXX.in%253A3093%252Ff3d870d084764d%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&locale=en_US&minimized=true&page_id=122137601YYYYYY&ref=8xCvg&sdk=joey' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://game.XXXXXX.in:3093"

YYYYYY contains my page id and XXXXXX contains my domain-url

I have figured out that there is some issue in origin URL when i render the plugin but i don't know what will be origin url if i render it in my FB app container. It Will render perfectly in normal html file(with origin = myappdomain:port)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain of your URL changes, you won't be able to use it, since you have to whitelist the domain the plugin will be rendered on.

Comment: i didn't chnaged my domain it remains same as my white listed url and I have added all possible URL in whitelist like my domain name, domain name with port number and also my app page url. But it doesn't work.